# Using join in node-red

Tags: node-red

Hello Guys i have a problem with join in node-red

[image: code]

I not able to join to the json string i only get out of the debug

[object object]

[image: debug]

Here is the flow code

```
[
    {
        "id": "7645aab16153a1b7",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "8f6bb36bd893800f",
        "name": "msg.payload",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "string",
        "property": "payload,msg.payload.kinput,msg.payload.kinout",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": "\\n",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "2",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "num",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 770,
        "y": 320,
        "wires": [
            [
                "7d2a6d44cbc779b0"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73578470/edit) the question to add more detail here. It's not clear from the question what output you are expecting and without some knowledge of what is in the `test.json` file we can't say if the output you got is correct. Also the flow you have posted only includes the join node details, not any of the other nodes, e.g. what the inject node is sending.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to make. 
This might help you.

```
[
{
    "id": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "플로우 1",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "8f6e87ae744403e1",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 120,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "86b1571e0eae5edd"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "86b1571e0eae5edd",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "function 15",
    "func": "msg.payload={\"kinput\":\"hi\"};\n\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 270,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "ba5d6f84c4e04dbf"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "ba5d6f84c4e04dbf",
    "type": "join",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "",
    "mode": "custom",
    "build": "merged",
    "property": "payload",
    "propertyType": "msg",
    "key": "topic",
    "joiner": "\\n",
    "joinerType": "str",
    "accumulate": false,
    "timeout": "",
    "count": "",
    "reduceRight": false,
    "reduceExp": "",
    "reduceInit": "",
    "reduceInitType": "num",
    "reduceFixup": "",
    "x": 430,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "1093997cfdf9092c"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1093997cfdf9092c",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "debug 27",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 560,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "28c9708ce3385b28",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 120,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        [
            "33749e60e7a441ae"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "33749e60e7a441ae",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "function 16",
    "func": "msg.payload={\"kinout\":\"hi2\"};\nmsg.complete=0;\n\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 270,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        [
            "ba5d6f84c4e04dbf"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "91c12d33c114fd4f",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "64a54fa5e2d177b2",
    "name": "Basic Join uses",
    "info": "",
    "x": 140,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": []
}
]
```

This flow is about basic uses of 'join' node.
I made simple function with merging msg.payload objects.

Comment: Answers should explain what the flow does

Comment: @hardillb ok i'll edit my answer.